# Importing a date field to Salesforce

Tags: data, import

I am importing data via a CSV file.  Everything is working except the date field.  In salesforce I have created a date field in Accounts for the incoming data.  When I use the import wizard and I get to the Accounts section I have chosen the proper column in the CSV file.  But when the import completes and I view the Accounts section of Salesforce the date fields are all blank.  What do I need to do to import the date fields?

Comment: How are you importing? Through the UI? Using a tool? What date format are you using now that doesn't seem to work?

Answer (score 1):

with the default data loader the standard date/time format is

```
yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.sssZ
```

but if you use Jitterbits data loader(FREE) (http://www.jitterbit.com/solutions/salesforce-integration/salesforce-data-loader/) it allows for a few more datetime formats including

```
mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss   (note should be in 24 hour time)
```

Important gotcha is that you set your timezone settings inside the jitterbit preferences, i assumed it used the time zone settings of the user connecting and was burned a few times.